# Where to get a climate database for all places of the world?

Tags: weather

I want to show some climate graphs and historical weather data for specific places around the world.

My current database has city names, countries, longitude, latitude possible to query a search in a climate database. There are a lot of weather api's but I search for static climate information, can't find anything on the internet. Database doesn't have to be updated, I don't expect the climate too change so fast.

XML, json even api is fine. Hope anyone can help me with this.

Format with max / min temperature per month, maybe average rainfall and sun hours would be great.

Comment: *I don't expect the climate too change so fast* Global warming skeptic, I see.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: no-one, not even climate scientists or raving greenies, expects climate to be statistically different year-to-year, and change is difficult to detect on any times scales shorter than a few decades.

Comment: you are right, data from 1980 is for my purpose exactly the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOAA keeps global climate data, Did you look at:

```
http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/ncdc.html
```

There seems to be an API:

```
http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices
```

Comment: thanks, maybe i was wrong about api is good too, any solutions for statistical database, even paid one is fine, if it is below 100$

Comment: I started an R wrapper to the NOAA climate data API here if interested https://github.com/ropensci/rnoaa

Comment: Stumbled on this answer and that site is shut down *currently* due to the US government being effectively shut down.  Talk about being held to ransom!

Comment: Check also `climate` package for R: github.com/bczernecki/climate. Also available on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/climate/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For very detailed climate Canada data I have only had luck w/ a
"URL based procedure to automatically download data in bulk from Climate Website".

You must then find the "station" you are interested in first here is the station list.
https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1egfzGgzUb0RFu_EE5AYFZtsyXPfZ11y2&export=download

One you have that you can request the data:
format:
[https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID={STATION}&Year={YEAR}&Month={MONTH}&Day={DAY}&timeframe=1](https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=%7BSTATION%7D&Year=%7BYEAR%7D&Month=%7BMONTH%7D&Day=%7BDAY%7D&timeframe=1)

Here is an example:
https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=10183&Year=2018&Month=3&Day=31&timeframe=1

You can find information on the columns here:
https://climate.weather.gc.ca/glossary_e.html#weather

And some general data information here:
https://climate.weather.gc.ca/about_the_data_index_e.html
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WJCDEU34c60IfOnG4rv5EPZ4IhhW9vZH